# Copying if cell have value/are not empty, while skipping multiple headers

Tags: excel, copy, vba

In my sheet "Inbox" there are multiple headers that don't need copying.

Headers are in rows 1-6, 24, 42, 60, 78 and 96. Total number of rows in a sheet is 130.

I would like to check is there a value (text or number) in column A, B, D or F of all 130 rows (headers excluded) and if there is, I would like to copy columns A-G of that row and paste special in sheet "Outbox" starting from row 7.
Both sheets are in same workbook and cells in sheet "Inbox" are formulas linked to another workbook.

Can someone please edit the code posted by user3819867 to ignore zero values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: we're here to help, not to do your job. We'd appreciate if you had at least a try at the code.
Second: you made a really good specification so my comments will help you write your next script yourself.

```
Sub ert()
j = 7
For i = 1 To 130 'Total number of rows in the sheet is 130.
If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, 1)) Or Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, 2)) Or Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, 4)) Or Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, 6)) Then 'A, B, D, F - at least one is not empty
    Select Case True
        Case i <= 6 Or i = 24 Or i = 42 Or i = 60 Or i = 78 Or i = 96 'Headers are in rows 1-6, 24, 42, 60, 78 and 96.
            'does nothing
        Case Else
            For k = 1 To 7 'A to G
                Sheets("Outbox").Cells(j, k).Value2 = Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, k).Value2 'copyies values
            Next
            j = j + 1 'next record in next row
    End Select
End If

Next
End Sub
```

A zero value is not a null value, thus "amendment" goes as:

```
Sub ert()
j = 7 'paste special in sheet "Outbox" starting from row 7.
For i = 1 To 130 'Total number of rows in the sheet is 130.
If Not 0 = (Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, 1)) Or Not 0 = (Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, 2)) Or Not 0 = (Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, 4)) Or Not 0 = (Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, 6)) Then 'A, B, D, F - at least one is not empty
    Select Case True
        Case i <= 6 Or i = 24 Or i = 42 Or i = 60 Or i = 78 Or i = 96 'Headers are in rows 1-6, 24, 42, 60, 78 and 96.
            'does nothing
        Case Else
            For k = 1 To 7 'A to G
                Sheets("Outbox").Cells(j, k).Value2 = Sheets("Inbox").Cells(i, k).Value2 'copyies values
            Next
            j = j + 1 'next record in next row
    End Select
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `j = 7 'paste special in sheet "Outbox" starting from row 7.`

Comment: I am sorry for being a nuisance. I wish I know more about coding and in time I will, but I just started using excel because of my job.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Code below works but it doesn't skip empty cells. Column C, E and G constantly have values so I don't want do search through them for values. It is very close to perfection. I'll try to edit the code my self with some luck. Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: Ok, I extensively tested the code and the problem is that formula I use produces zero values. All the fields in my sheet have a simple formula "=" that imports data from different workbooks. Although source sheet doesn't have any value in cells, formula produces zero value in destination workbook which causes the problem. I'll try to google for solution.

Comment: Edited, IsEmpty(~~~) is now 0 = (~~~). Null values - I believe - equal 0. Let me know if they don't.

Comment: You're a life saver.It works absolutely perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: If my solution/answer has covered your question feel free to upvote/accept as the answer. This will enable me to get help when I need it by offering bounties.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but this should work:

```
Sub test()
Dim inbox As Worksheet
Dim outbox As Worksheet
Set inbox = Sheets("Inbox")
Set outbox = Sheets("Outbox")
Dim lastrowOutbox As Integer
lastrowOutbox = outbox.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows.Row
inbox.Activate

For i = 2 To 130

If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) Or Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) Or Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4).Value) Or Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5).Value) Then
    Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Copy Destination:=outbox.Range("A" & lastrowOutbox & ":G" & lastrowOutbox)
    lastrowOutbox = lastrowOutbox + 1
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

It copy to the first empty cell in Output.

Comment: I tried. It still doesn't ignore formula/zero values.  Also in "Outbox" first row displays #REF! error.

Comment: what do you mean with formula/zero values? how does your input look like? You wrote to check if a value is in the cell

Comment: Ok, my sheet "Inbox" has simple formula "=" that imports data from other workbooks. Even though source workbooks are empty formula produces zero values that I have hidden. VBA provided by user3819867 "Sub ert" works perfectly, except it detects those zero values and basically copies entire sheet.

Comment: @katz OP implies that zeros are null values, well nope. He also wrote "paste special" without specifying which [pastespecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) options he intended to use. Both our solutions are fitting his description.

Comment: @MJ54 Feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you